# Is it possible to combine rst-class and ifconfig?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing on a software documentation. I am using the `.. rst-cass::` directive to add specific css classes to different sections which control different styles and features, which works really well. Now I tried to create different versions of the document and therefore tried to combine `.. rst-cass::`  with `.. ifconfig::`. My `.rst` files looked like this:

```
.. ifconfig::  var==True
      
   .. rst-class:: html-toggle  

.. ifconfig::  var==False
      
   .. rst-class:: grey     

Sectiontitle
============
```

When I tried to build this into HTML files, the build process didn´t finish and showed me:

> 'Losing "%s" attribute: %s' % (att, self[att])
>
> AssertionError: Losing "classes" attribute: ['html-toggle']

Is there any way this can work, or any other way, where to assign CSS classes to sections depending on variables in the `conf.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom CSS, instead of adding classes to the HTML, and selecting which style sheet to use in your `conf.py` with a Python expression.

[`ifconfig` is intended to](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/ifconfig.html) "include content of the directive only if the Python expression given as an argument is True", not customizing styles.